# Styling HTML created inside external php file

Tags: php, html

I have a html file (index.html) which when loaded calls a colorbox after 5 seconds.
The colorbox opens another html file (popup.html) which has a form for users to submit details.

On submit the form calls a php file which generates and sends an email. Once sent a success message is displayed on popup.html.

```
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- success html -->

<div class="popup_message"><h2>Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.</h2></div> 

<?php
}

die();
?>
```

The issue i am having is that i am attempting to style the popup_message H2 element using a global CSS file (defined in both index.html and popup.html), however it does not style the output.

Do i need to be defining the file within the php file also ?

---

Here is my php file, i tried adding the HTML code around the DIV but this just prevented the success message from showing:

```
    <?php
    echo

    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

        $mobile_error = "";

        $email_to = "contactus@complete-models.com";

        $email_subject = "7 Day free pass interest";


        function died($error) {
            // your error code can go here
            echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
            echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
            echo $error."<br /><br />";
            echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
            die();
        }

        // validation expected data exists
        if( !isset($_POST['first_name']) || !isset($_POST['mobile']) || !isset($_POST['email']) ) {
            died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
        }

        $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
        $mobile = $_POST['mobile']; // required
        $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

        $error_message = "";
        $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
        if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
                $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
        }

        $mobile_exp = '[0-9]';
        if(!preg_match($mobile_exp, $mobile)) {
                $error_message .= 'The Mobile number you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
        }

        $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
        if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
                $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
        }
        $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

        function clean_string($string) {
          $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
          return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
        }

        $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Mobile: ".clean_string($mobile)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";


    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
    ?>

    <!-- success html below -->

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/screen_style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
            <div class="popup_message"><h2>Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.</h2></div> 
    </body>
</html>

    <?php
    }
    die();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to be defining the CSS in the PHP file, too. In fact, the PHP document should contain fully formed HTML, which is to say it should include: `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags.

This is because the PHP file is its own separate file, just like index.html and popup.html.

Comment: sorry this did not work for me. See php file added in description.

Comment: Where's your DOCTYPE and title tags...? Here's an example of an empty valid HTML document: https://shrib.com/4Bz7ODAfqs1e3ol Also make sure the URL to the CSS is correct and it's not coming up 404 in Developer Tools.